# Is there a name for this function or pattern?

Tags: function, haskell, typeclass

Instead of `fmap`, which applies a function to a value-in-a-functor:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I needed a function where the functor has a function and the value is plain:

```
thing :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b
```

but I [can't find one](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Functor%20f%20=%3E%20f%20%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20f%20b).

What is this pattern called, where I apply a function-in-a-functor (or in an applicative, or in a monad) to a plain value?

<sub><sub>I've implemented it already, I just don't quite understand what I did and why there wasn't already such a function in the standard libraries.</sub></sub>

Comment: Isn't this just a special case of an Applicative? Like `func <*> pure value`?

Comment: Notice that the type is very similar to `ap` and `<*>`.  Although I don't see a corresponding `Functor` version, and this can be implemented without assuming `Applicative`s or `Monad`s:  `thing fs x = fmap (\f -> f x) fs`

Comment: Yep, lambdabot says `thing = (.pure) . (<*>)` or `thing = flip (fmap . flip id)`. But I get it that this isn't what you want to know :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, although the first one does require Applicatives, and my intuition doesn't work for the second one. :( :(

Comment: Yeah, the second one is not really useful.

Comment: @MattFenwick - how do you know that it can be implemented without assuming `Applicative`?  Is this a challenge problem or something?  Edit, n/m I just saw your tiny footnote.

Comment: @Niklas B. The second one seems to be quite useful.  It's the point-free form of `fmap ($ x) f` (to see this, note that `($)` and `id` actually mean the same thing... except that `($)` has a more restrictive type), while the first is `f <*> pure x`, which by the `Applicative` laws is equivalent to `pure ($ x) <*> f`, which is just `fmap ($ x) f`.  In other words, these two mean the same thing, except that the first one requires `Applicative` for no good reason.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need `Applicative` for this; `Functor` will do just fine:

```
apply f x = fmap ($ x) f
-- or, expanded:
apply f x = fmap (\f' -> f' x) f
```

Interestingly, `apply` is actually a generalisation of `flip`; [lambdabot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambdabot) replaces `flip` with this definition as one of its generalisations of standard Haskell, so that's a possible name, although a confusing one.

By the way, it's often worth trying [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) (which searches the entirety of Hackage, unlike Hoogle) to see what names a function is often given, and whether it's in any generic package. Searching for [`f (a -> b) -> a -> f b`](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=f%20%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20f%20b&start=0), it finds `flip` (in [`Data.Functor.Syntax`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/functors/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor-Syntax.html), from the [`functors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/functors) package) and `($#)` (from the [`synthesizer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/synthesizer) package) as possible names. Still, I'd probably just use `fmap ($ arg) f` at the use site.

Answer (score 6):

As Niklas says, this is application in some applicative functor to a lifted value.

```
\f a -> f <*> pure a

:: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b
```

or more generally (?), using [Category](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Category.html) `(.)`

```
\f a -> f . pure a

:: (Applicative (cat a), Category cat) => cat b c -> b -> cat a c
```